# Customize the layout of the title of a Dialog

Tags: android, xml, dialog, title

I need to customize the **title area** of a my custom dialog using the following layout:

dialog_title.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text" 
    android:text="@string/tell_a_friend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingTop="12dip"
    android:paddingBottom="12dip"
    style="@style/bigTextWhite" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm creating my dialog using a CustomDialog class that extends Dialog.

```
CustomDialog dialogTellAFriend = new CustomDialog(this, Constants.TELL_A_FRIEND_DIALOG);    
dialogTellAFriend.show();
```

How do I make this happen?

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know if there is a way to inflate that xml in the title area of the dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to hide your dialog title and inflate whole dialog by your xml. I think this Idea is best for you.

**For hide the Dialog title**

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and **load your layout for dialog is**

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks. But I'm not sure this is the best way to do it.